# How to install a program that has a binary file in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

I am currently using Linux Mint in virtual box, and I am trying to install Quartus. I keep getting:

```
setup.sh:setup.sh: cannot execute binary file
```

I would like to know how to install the mentioned app or a step-by-step instruction on how to install any software a Linux Mint environment that has binary file.

I have downloaded the folder for Quartus Prime for Linux.

Comment: Did you `chmod +x` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess with the limited information you've supplied, I would say the binary file isn't executable or the user you are using does not have permissions to execute it. Check the file perms with `ls -l <filename>`, does it have the x permission? Make it executable with the command `chmod +x <filename>`.

Comment: I typed ls - setup.sh. The result is "-rw-rw-- 1". Then I did, chmod -x setup.sh. What is next?

Comment: As I suspected, no executable permission. It should be something like -rwxrwxr-x.

Comment: What should I do if I encounter this?

Comment: @eLg, it's in my frickin' answer!

Comment: I reread it. My bad